# Problem with session of magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, session

whenever I activate the option 'Validate REMOTE_ADDR' it happens this error. I don't know what to do...

```
The "remote_addr" session value is invalid. Verify and try again.
```

and in admin, i'm redirected to luma

Comment: You tried incognito of any other browser or delete and clear all cache and cookies

Comment: Yes! still the error persists

Comment: https://www.rootways.com/blog/how-to-validate-remote-addr-in-magento-2